# OpenJDK 1.8 which configuaration will take effect, when set /dev/urandom?

Tags: java

we know that there are two options to let `SecureRandom` to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`:

1. change `JRE_PATH/lib/security/java.security` file
2. set jvm property `-Djava.security.egd`

but which one take effect when setting both ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation in `<java_dir>/jre/lib/security/java.security` clearly says:

> The entropy gathering device can also be specified with the System
>   property "java.security.egd". For example:
>
> `% java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/random MainClass`
>
> **Specifying this System property will override the
>   "securerandom.source" Security property.**

So the system property will always have precedence when set.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation?

Comment: @Michael The documentation is directly in the `java.security` file in the java installation.